# Prove the polynomial is irreducible on the prime field $F_2$

Tags: polynomials

How to prove that $$x^{2^n}+x+1$$ is irreducible in $F_2$

-Is this question relevant to finite field?

Comment: @CalvinLin It might still be the product of two smaller degree polynomials (which also have no roots in $\mathbb F_2$).

Comment: You might be interested in this
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122274/why-xpn-x1-is-irreducible-in-mathbbf-p-only-when-n-1-or-n-p-2

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, I realized that soon after, when I tried factoring it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove it because it's not true: $x^8+x+1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+1)$.

Comment: thanks. This problem is from my textbook on Abstract Algebra. I find that book has many errors.