# Is the polynomial $x^8+x+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Is the polynomial $f(x)=x^8+x+1$ irreducible inf $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$?

I know that if $x^8+x+1$ divides $x^{2^8}-x=x^{256}-x$, then it is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$. I started using the division algorithm to see if this is true, but its too painful.

Is there a quick way to do this that I do not see? Can we show that $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(f(x))$ is a field (or not)?

Comment: I hope you didn't mean anything special by capital "$X$".

Comment: Are you familiar with Berlekamp's algorithm?

Comment: If $f$ is reducible, then at least one factor will have degree at most 4, and the constant term of every factor is $1$. That gives you $2^4-1=15$ possible factors to check, which should be pretty quick.

Comment: This is a special case of [the more general result of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/122274/11619).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x^8 = -x-1$, then $x^{256}-x = x^{256}+x = (x+1)^{32}-x = x^{32} + x + 1$ $= (x+1)^4 + x + 1 = x^4 + x$.

So $x^{256}-x \equiv x^4 + x \pmod{x^8 + x + 1}$, and we can reduce no further.  Therefore $x^8 + x + 1$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Concretely, we have $x^8 + x + 1 = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1)$.