# Factorization of $X^{p^n}-X-c$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

When looking through some old exercises, I have found one which stumped me a bit, and which has been bugging me for quite a few days. The question is how the polynomial $X^{p^n}-X-c$ factorizes over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ (with $c \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$). The case when $n=1$ is easy, we find that the polynomial is irreducible. However in the more general case, it gets quite hard! I can't (I think) easily generalize the argument I used for when $n=1$, there I just used that if $r$ is a root of the polynomial in question we also find that $r \notin \mathbb{F}_{p}$ and that $r+i$ is a root for all $i \in \mathbb{F}_p$. The rest follows by looking at the explicit factorization over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$

However when $n \neq 1$, I can't easily use the fact that $r \notin \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. So my earlier arguments stops working, there's a hint that I could look at how the Frobenius automorphism acts on the roots of our polynomial, so i think I could use something about our polynomial being separable, however I didn't really see how. Any hints or answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1574164/11619) help? Or possibly [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/579659/11619)?

Comment: Not really, I'm actually specifically looking for a solution using Frobenius acting on the roots. We also haven't talked about the trace in class  so I have a feeling it should be possible to proof it without this. But thanks :)

Comment: I see. May be [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/122283/11619) can be adapted? The idea would be that if $\alpha$ is a zero of your polynomial from some extension field of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$, then we get
$$F(\alpha)=\alpha^{p^n}=\alpha+c$$
for the Frobenius conjugate $F(\alpha)$. Given that $c^{p^n}=c$ repeating the dose reveals that that $p$th iterate $F^p(\alpha)=\alpha$, Therefore $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{p^{pn}}$ et cetera.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Maybe it's a dumb question but I don't really see why $\alpha^{p^n}$ would equal $\alpha+c$ at the moment. I do however get at the rest. We could use this using $\alpha$'s minimum polynomial right? If $m$ is said minimum polynomial we find that $deg(m) | pn$ and also $deg(m)|p^n$, and then we could do something else weird with $m$. I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense though, I'm having quite a hard time with this question and class. So still thanks :)

Comment: Remember that $\alpha$ satisfies the equation
$$\alpha^{p^n}-\alpha-c=0.$$ This implies that $\alpha^{p^n}=\alpha+c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this approach? I hope that @JyrkiLahtonen will examine it closely, since I’m not completely convinced that all is well.

Call $p^n=q$, $k=\Bbb F_q$, $F(x)=x^q-x-c\in k[x]$, and $\varphi$ the $q$-Frobenius, sending $\xi\in\bar k$ to $\xi\,^q$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $F$, i.e. of a $k$-irreducible factor $g$ of $F$. The $k$-conjugates of $\alpha$ are the finitely many $\varphi^m\alpha$, and the number of these is the degree of $g$. Now, $\varphi\alpha=\alpha^q=\alpha+c$, $\varphi^2\alpha=\varphi(\alpha+c)=\varphi\alpha+c=\alpha+2c$, and indeed $\varphi^n=\alpha+nc$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z$. Thus, if $c\ne0$, the number of $k$-conjugates of $\alpha$ is precisely $p$, and the irreducible factor $g$ of $F$ is of degree $p$.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what happens.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, that's also the way how I solved the question (after long hours of thinking hahaha). Sorry I responded so late! I forgot about it. This argument is solid though right? One could use that the polynomial ring over the algebraic closure is a unique factorization ring, to make the argument that all irreducible factors should be of degree $p$ more rigorous I thought

Comment: what is $\bar k$?

Comment: Should be a given, fixed, algebraic closure of $k$, @Emptymind .