# Degree of factors of the Artin–Schreier polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Consider the field $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is a power of $p$, say $q=p^n$. Let $f=x^q-x-a\in\mathbb{F}_q[x]$, with $a\in\mathbb{F}_q$.
I'm trying to determine the degree of the irreducible factors of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$.
Now I already solved this for $a=0$, since,
$$x^q-x=x^{p^n}-x=\prod_{g \text{ monic, irreducible, deg}(g)\mid n}g,$$
but, for $a\neq 0$, I can't seem to make any progress at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [Irreducible factors for $x^q-x-a$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579659/irreducible-factors-for-xq-x-a-in-mathbbf-p)

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but in the link you suggested the question is how $f$ factors in $\mathbb{F}_p$, but that is not what I'm asking. I'm interested what the degrees are of the factors in $\mathbb{F}_q$ (not $\mathbb{F}_p$, nor am I interested what the actual factors are, although of course, they could be of use).

Comment: There is also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2171681/11619) and many others linked to the thread Shean suggested.

Comment: In other words, the irreducible factors in $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ all have degree $p$.