# Confusion on "uniqueness of roots" in fields

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

> I am in the process of solving the following problem: $x^{p^n}-x+1$ is irreducible only when $n=1$ or $n=p=2$ over $F_p$.
>
> The hint is to note that if $\alpha$ is a root, then $\alpha +a$, $a \in F_{p^n}$ is a root. I am supposed to use this to show that $F_p(\alpha)$ contains $F_{p^n}$ and that $[F_p(\alpha):F_{p^n}]=p$.

I was thinking about this problem and it got me very confused, mainly the first part. I am torn because assuming the polynomial is irreducible, $F_p(\alpha)$ is a finite extension so it must be Galois, so normal and so $F_p(\alpha)$ is a splitting field. This means that $F_p(\alpha)$ has all the zeroes of $f$.

My question is, are they of the "form" $\alpha +a$? This would imply $F_{p^n}$ is contained in the splitting field. My idea is just to say take two roots, subtract them, and you get an element of $F_{p^n}$ but i am not sure how to formalize this. Hopefully my confusion is clear: roots are unique, but their representations are not.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of [this oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122274/11619). If there is something that is not clear to you after studying those answers, please let me know. Otherwise I'm inclined to vote to close this as a duplicate. It is a nice question and the reason for the exception with $p=n=2$ is a bit subtle. But the answers there are rather perfect IMO.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Question is not about the problem per se, but rather about the confusions that were brought upon by the problem. I thought including it would be helpful to understand what I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $x \to x^{p^n}$ is a **Frobenius automorphism**. It is an automorphism of any field of characteristic $p$. It's **fixed field** is the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.

> if $\alpha$ is a root, then $\alpha+a$, is a root for every $a\in
> > \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.

**All equalities are equalities $\mod p$.**
Let $\alpha$ be a root, and $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Write $q := p^n$. Then we have

$$(\alpha + a)^{q} = \sum_{i=0}^q \binom{q}{i} \alpha^i \cdot a^{q-i} = \alpha^q + a^q$$
since for every i with $0<i<q$, $p$ divides $\binom{q}{i}$ hence $\binom{q}{i} = 0 \mod p$.

Now, since $a\in \mathbb{F}^q$, we have $a^q=a$. Hence,
$$(\alpha + a)^q -(\alpha + a) +1 = \alpha^q + a^q - \alpha - a +1 = \alpha^q - \alpha + 1 =0$$ 
QED

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I know that all such elements are zeroes in $F_{p^n}$ but are they of the same form in $F_p(\alpha)$ ?

Comment: @Sorfosh Why does their form matter? Maybe you want to know that all the roots are of the form $\alpha + a$ for $a \in \mathbb{F}_{q}$, but that's just a mathematical way of saying "the roots we've already found are the only roots".

Comment: besides, I'm working in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ all along.

Comment: I understand that these are the roots, in $F_{p^n}(\alpha)$ however, it is not clear these are the same roots in $F_p(\alpha)$.

Comment: As you pointed out, $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ must contain all roots of this polynomial since we assumed it is irreducible.

Comment: Hence, $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ contains $\mathbb{F}_q$, by the way.

Comment: I think i understand what you are saying. If we are in the algebraic closure of $F_p$ we know that the roots are $\alpha +a$ in there. But the algebraic closure contains $F_p(\alpha)$ so the roots there must also be of the form $\alpha+a$.

Comment: I think what confused me is that you can have "different roots." $x^2+1$ has 1 as a root in $F_2$ but not in $C$. Whats important is that the fields have the same algebraic closure, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what makes every thing smooth.