# $p$ is a prime number, $\, n\ge1 \, $and$ \, n \nmid p^n$.If $a \in GF(p)$, proof $x^{p^n}-x-a$ is reducible in $GF(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I know that in a field $F$ with character $p$($p$ is a prime number), we have  $x^{p^n}-x-a \,(a \in F)$ is reducible \iff $x^{p^n}-x-a$ has root in $F$  Then the question is to prove $x^{p^n}-x-a \, \equiv \, 0 \, $(mod $p$) has solution.

Comment: Very closely [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122274/11619).

Comment: I don't think that polynomial has a solutions in $GF(p)$ (unless $a=0$), but it is reducible. If $\alpha$ is a root (in some extension field), then $\alpha^{p^n}=\alpha+a$ implying that $\alpha^{p^{np}}=\alpha$. Therefore the number of conjugates of $\alpha$ over $GF(p)$ is at most $np$ which is less than $p^n$, and we are done.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate assuming that the formulation in your title is the intended one. If not, please clarify.

Comment: Thank you . That equivalence is not true.